# Understanding JavaScript inheritance when converting C# to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to understand prototypical inheritance. Can someone translate this C# to JS for me?

```
public class FormElement { }

public class Rectangle : FormElement {
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class TextRectangle : Rectangle {
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note: I don't think JS has properties, so those will propably decay to normal public fields.

Comment: @delnan Typically, properties can be mimicked by converting into get_Property() and set_Property(value) functions and keeping the variables private.

Comment: Note that "private" variables only exist in JavaScript when using a pseudo-classical design paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

```
var FormElement = function() {}

var Rectangle = function() {
    // Set Everything
    this.Top = 3;
    this.Left = 3;
    this.Width = 3;
    this.Height = 3;
}

Rectangle.prototype = new FormElement();

var TextRectangle = function() {
    this.Text = '';
}

TextRectangle.prototype = new Rectangle();
```

Something like that

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mePch/

So now you can do something like:

```
var TR = new TextRectangle();

console.log(TR.Height); //outputs: 3
```

Comment: But then you have to do `this.Rectangle.Top = 4` that's a right mess.

Comment: Instances via public properties are a bad idea. In classical languages, these are "public static" variables (accessible through import of class without instantiation). Use `Rectangle.prototype = new FormElement();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have classical inheritance. So it's going to be completely different. You should read up on [Prototypical OO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) and read up on [Self](http://selflanguage.org/).

```
var Rectangle = {
    area: function() { return this.width * this.height; }
};

var rectangle = function(obj) {
    return Object.create(Rectangle, pd(obj);
};

var rect = rectangle({
    "top": 10,
    "left": 10,
    "width": 10,
    "height": 10
});
rect.area(); // 100
// ...

var TextAble = {
    printText: function() { console.log(this.text); }  
};

var textRectangle = function(obj) { 
    return pd.merge(rectangle(obj), TextAble);
};

var textrect = textrectangle({
    "top": 10,
    "left": 10,
    "height": 10,
    "width": 10,
    "text": "some text"
});
textrect.printText(); // "some text",
textrect.area(); // 100
```

Above code uses [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to portray prototypical OO meaning. It also uses [pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd)

Answer (score 1):

Object factories are a great way to go in JS:

```
var makeRectangle = function(t, l, w, h)
{
    return {
        top: t || 0,
        left: l || 0,
        width: w || 0,
        height: h || 0
    };
}

var makeTextRectangle = function(t, l, w, h, text)
{
    var rect = makeRectangle(t, l, w, h);
    rect.text = text || '';
    return rect;
}
```

Or, to take advantage of the prototype:

```
var makeTextRectangle = function(t, l, w, h, text)
{
    var rect = Object.create(makeRectangle(t, l, w, h));
    rect.text = text || '';
    return rect;
}
```

Though you'll need to add `Object.create` where it is not already implemented (via [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)):

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Comment: Why not use `new` and `this` :\

Comment: Why bother with the confusion of adding `new` to a prototype-based inheritance system? I know I'm not really taking advantage of the prototype here (just add `Object.create()` with an argument of `makeRectangle(...)`), but the indirection that `new` uses tends to cause confusion.

Comment: that's just a matter of learning how `new` and `this` works. I think it makes code cleaner. [Love ES5](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/UWnAv/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the direct translation you're looking for, but if you're interested in interactions between C# objects and JavaScript objects then [ExoWeb](https://github.com/vc3/exoweb) may have some very interesting source code for you to study.  A simplified description of the project is that it creates a translation layer between server-side models in C# and client-side models in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's Extend method (other libraries have some analagous feature), you could do something like this:

```
function FormElement() { }

function Rectangle() { }
$.extend(true, Rectangle.prototype, FormElement.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.top = function(val) { if (arguments.length == 0) return this._top; else this._top = val; };
Rectangle.prototype.left = function(val) { if (arguments.length == 0) return this._left; else this._left = val; };
Rectangle.prototype.width = function(val) { if (arguments.length == 0) return this._width; else this._width = val; };
Rectangle.prototype.height = function(val) { if (arguments.length == 0) return this._height; else this._height = val; };

function TextRectangle() { }
$.extend(true, TextRectangle.prototype, Rectangle.prototype);
TextRectangle.prototype.text = function(val) { if (arguments.length == 0) return this._text; else this._text = val; };

var rect = new TextRectangle();
rect.top(5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8H9cL/